# Get boolean variable from XML (not string)

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

Is it possible with Javascript (or jQuery to make example easier) get boolean variable from some field in XML?
If so - how it should be written in XML and what actions should be made on client side?

Please check the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var data = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?><data><event id='2'><text><![CDATA[Hello there]]></text><bool1>true</bool1><bool2>false</bool2></event></data>";
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data);
    var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
    var bool = data.find("bool1").text(); // "true" - string
});
```

What I would like here is to get string for the 'test' field and boolean for 'bool1'/'bool2'.

Thank you.

**Update:** So one either have to set up XML scheme or simply make direct comparisons ( === 'false' / === 'true' ) and convert that way to boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the read in text to the string "true", and assign the results of that comparison into your variable.

```
var b = data.find("bool1").text() === 'true';
```

In case of an extra whitespace in the text node, you could use jQuery to trim the read in text:

```
var b = $.trim(data.find("bool1").text()) === 'true';
```

If the node holds the text "true" (with some possible surrounding whitespace), then the variable will receive the boolean value of `true`. If the node holds ANY value other than the string "true", the variable will receive the boolean value of `false`.

Comment: That of course would work but looking for a more robust solution. Also would be perfect to distinguish strings with 'true' and boolean true in XML.

Comment: XML doesn't have the notion of a boolean without a schema definition, and I'm not sure how much more "robust" you'd like this to be.

Comment: So basically it's impossible to make XML distinguish string 'true' and the boolean variable? Because if I simply used above method too all fields I would lose 'true'/'false' string if they happen to be there.

Comment: You need to write a schema for your XML if you want node values to represent something other than a string. Otherwise, you'll have to read it in and compare it.

Comment: Thanks for the accept. Based on the edit by Sérgio Michels, however, I suggest you review and test his new answer. If it works for you, feel free to change your acceptance to his answer. --Jim

Comment: All answers were really useful, indeed. Thank you. You were the first though :) In my case I can only partly change formed XML file (and that's why can't use attributes or schema). Noted for the future though.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you can just wrap your XML string in a jQuery object to parse it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $data = $("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?><data><event id='2'><text><![CDATA[Hello there]]></text><bool1>true</bool1><bool2>false</bool2></event></data>");
    var bool = $data.find("bool1").text(); // "true" - string
});
```

Then to force a variable to be Boolean you can set it's value with a conditional statement like this:

```
var bool = ($data.find("bool1").text() == 'false') ? false : true;
```

Comment: Using double bang (!!) will result in bool `true` for any truthy value, including the string "false". The link you posted in your edit confirms that, and shows to use the result of a comparison to the string "true".

Comment: @JAAulde Thanks for that comment, very true. I guess the most elegant solution is to check if the string value is either `"true"` or `"false"` and set the Boolean accordingly.

Comment: No problem. Indeed, the comparison is what is needed, and since that comparison results in a bool, it can be directly assigned into the var.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can convert your text to boolean, simple like that:</strike>
<strike>var bool = Boolean($xml.find('bool1').text());</strike>

**EDIT**: this always return true. You need indeed test as String.

To distinct string and boolean in xml, you can add the type attribute:

```
<bool1 type='xs:boolean'>false</bool1>

$xml.find('bool1').attr('type') //returns xs:boolean
```

Comment: Wouldn't any string passed into the `Boolean` function result in a true value?